# need help determining why output is always leonard wins all games

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Constants - These constants will help improve the readability of your code
SHELDON = "Sheldon"
LEONARD = "Leonard"

LEONARD_WINS = 0
SHELDON_WINS = 1
TIE = 2

ROCK = 0
PAPER = 1
SCISSORS = 2
LIZARD = 3
SPOCK = 4

# Variables - Use these variables in your code to track the program's progress
leonardsShape = 0
sheldonsShape = 0 
roundsToPlay = 0

leonardsWinCount = 0
sheldonsWinCount = 0
tieCount = 0

def convertShapeToText(shape):
    choices = {ROCK : "Rock", PAPER : "Paper", SCISSORS : "Scissors", LIZARD : "Lizard", SPOCK : "Spock"}
    return choices.get(shape, "default")

# =======================================================================================================
# DO NOT MODIFY any of the code above this point
# ========================================================================================================


# It's OK to change these constants (use the shape names above - ROCK, SCISSORS, PAPER, LIZARD, SPOCK)
# See the Initial Values in the provided examples
SHELDONS_FIRST_SHAPE = ROCK 
LEONARDS_FIRST_SHAPE = ROCK
NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS = 4
print ("Jason Bolling")
print ("project 4: Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock")
def determineLeonardsNextShape(roundOutcome) :
    global leonardsShape
    global sheldonsShape
    if leonardsShape == 0 :
      if roundOutcome == 0 :
        return determineLeonardsNextShape == 0
      elif roundOutcome == 1 :
        if sheldonsShape == 4 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
        elif sheldonsShape == 3 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 0
        elif sheldonsShape == 0 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
        elif sheldonsShape == 1 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
        elif sheldonsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
      elif roundOutcome == 2 :
        if leonardsShape == 0 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
        elif leonardsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
        elif leonardsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
        elif leonardsShape == 3 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape ==  0
        elif leonardsShape == 4 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
    elif leonardsShape == 1 :
      if roundOutcome == 0 :
        return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
      elif roundOutcome == 1 :
        if sheldonsShape == 4 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
        elif sheldonsShape == 3 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 0
        elif sheldonsShape == 0 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
        elif sheldonsShape == 1 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
        elif sheldonsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
      elif roundOutcome == TIE :
        if leonardsShape == 0 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
        elif leonardsShape == 1 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
        elif leonardsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
        elif leonardsShape == 3 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape ==  0
        elif leonardsShape == 4 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
    elif leonardsShape == 2 :
      if roundOutcome == 0 :
        return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
      elif roundOutcome == 1 :
        if sheldonsShape == 4 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
        elif sheldonsShape == 3 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 0
        elif sheldonsShape == 0 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
        elif sheldonsShape == 1 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
        elif sheldonsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
      elif roundOutcome == 2 :
        if leonardsShape == 0 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
        elif leonardsShape == 1 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
        elif leonardsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
        elif leonardsShape == 3 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape ==  0
        elif leonardsShape == 4 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
    elif leonardsShape == 3 :
      if roundOutcome == 0 :
        return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
      elif roundOutcome == 1 :
        if sheldonsShape == 4 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
        elif sheldonsShape == 3 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 0
        elif sheldonsShape == 0 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
        elif sheldonsShape == 1 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
        elif sheldonsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
      elif roundOutcome == 2 :
        if leonardsShape == 0 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
        elif leonardsShape == 1 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
        elif leonardsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
        elif leonardsShape == 3 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape ==  0
        elif leonardsShape == 4 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
    elif leonardsShape == 4 :
      if roundOutcome == 0 :
        return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
      elif roundOutcome == 1 :
        if sheldonsShape == 4 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
        elif sheldonsShape == 3 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 0
        elif sheldonsShape == 0 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
        elif sheldonsShape == 1 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
        elif sheldonsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
      elif roundOutcome == 2 :
        if leonardsShape == 0 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 1
        elif leonardsShape == 1 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 2
        elif leonardsShape == 2 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 4
        elif leonardsShape == 3 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape ==  0
        elif leonardsShape == 4 :
          return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
      return

def determineSheldonsNextShape(roundOutcome):
    global leonardsShape
    global sheldonsShape
    if roundsToPlay == {2, 4} :
      return sheldonsShape == 4
    elif sheldonsShape == 0 :
      if roundOutcome == 1 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 0
      elif roundOutcome == 0 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 1
      elif roundOutcome == 2 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 3
    elif sheldonsShape == 1 :
      if roundOutcome == 1 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 0
      elif roundOutcome == 0 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 1
      elif roundOutcome == 2 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 3
    elif sheldonsShape == 3 :
      if roundOutcome == 1 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 0
      elif roundOutcome == 0 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 1
      elif roundOutcome == 2 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 3
    elif sheldonsShape == 4 :
      if roundOutcome == 1 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 0
      elif roundOutcome == 0 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 1
      elif roundOutcome == 2 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 3
    elif sheldonsShape == 2 :
      if roundOutcome == 1 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 0
      elif roundOutcome == 0 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 1
      elif roundOutcome == 2 :
        return determineSheldonsNextShape == 3
    return

def determineWinner():
    global leonardsShape
    global sheldonsShape
    if sheldonsShape == 0 and leonardsShape == 0 :
      return determineWinner == TIE
    elif sheldonsShape == 0 and leonardsShape == 1 :
      return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 0 and leonardsShape == 2 :
      return determineWinner == SHELDON_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 0 and leonardsShape == 3 :
      return determineWinner == SHELDON_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 0 and leonardsShape == 4 :
      return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 1 and leonardsShape == 0 :
      return determineWinner == SHELDON_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 1 and leonardsShape == 1 :
      return determineWinner == TIE
    elif sheldonsShape == 1 and leonardsShape == 2 :
      return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 1 and leonardsShape == 3 :
      return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS 
    elif sheldonsShape == 1 and leonardsShape == 4 :
      return determineWinner == SHELDON_WINS 
    elif sheldonsShape == 2 and leonardsShape == 0 :
      return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 2 and leonardsShape == 1 :
      return determineWinner == SHELDON_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 2 and leonardsShape == 2 :
      return determineWinner == TIE
    elif sheldonsShape == 2 and leonardsShape == 3 :
      return determineWinner == SHELDON_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 2 and leonardsShape == 4 :
      return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 3 and leonardsShape == 0 :
      return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 3 and leonardsShape == 1 :
      return determineWinner == SHELDON_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 3 and leonardsShape == 2 :
      return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 3 and leonardsShape == 3 :
      return determineWinner == TIE
    elif sheldonsShape == 3 and leonardsShape == 4 :
      return determineWinner == SHELDON_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 4 and leonardsShape == 0 :
      return determineWinner == SHELDON_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 4 and leonardsShape == 1 :
      return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 4 and leonardsShape == 2 :
      return determineWinner == SHELDON_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 4 and leonardsShape == 3 :
      return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS
    elif sheldonsShape == 4 and leonardsShape == 4 :
      return determineWinner == TIE
    return

def getBetterShape(shape):
  if shape == 0 :
    return getBetterShape == 1
  elif shape == 1 :
    return getBetterShape == 2
  elif shape == 2 :
    return getBetterShape == 4
  elif shape == 3 :
    return getBetterShape == 0
  elif shape == 4 :
    return getBetterShape == 3
  return
 # =======================================================================================================
# DO NOT MODIFY any of the code below this point
# =======================================================================================================       
def displayResults():
    print("{0}'s initial move: {1}\n{2}'s initial move: {3}\n\n".format(SHELDON, convertShapeToText(SHELDONS_FIRST_SHAPE), LEONARD, convertShapeToText(LEONARDS_FIRST_SHAPE)))
    if sheldonsWinCount > leonardsWinCount:
        print("{0} wins! ".format(SHELDON))
    elif leonardsWinCount > sheldonsWinCount:
        print("{0} wins! ".format(LEONARD))
    else:
        print("Tie Game!")
    if not sheldonsWinCount == leonardsWinCount:
        print("{0} won {1} game(s), {2} won {3} game(s), and they tied {4} game(s)\n".format(SHELDON, sheldonsWinCount, LEONARD, leonardsWinCount, tieCount))
    else:
        print("{0} and {1} each won {2} game(s) and tied {3} game(s)\n".format(SHELDON, LEONARD, sheldonsWinCount, tieCount))

def playGame():
    global leonardsShape, sheldonsShape

    for x in range(0, roundsToPlay):
        outcome = determineWinner()
        updateScores(outcome)
        leonardsShape = determineLeonardsNextShape(outcome)
        sheldonsShape = determineSheldonsNextShape(outcome)

def updateScores(roundOutcome):
    global leonardsWinCount, sheldonsWinCount, tieCount

    if roundOutcome == SHELDON_WINS:
        sheldonsWinCount = sheldonsWinCount + 1
    elif roundOutcome == LEONARD_WINS:
        leonardsWinCount = leonardsWinCount + 1
    else:
        tieCount = tieCount + 1

def main():
    print("Ima Python Programmer\nRock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock\n")
    playGame()
    displayResults()

leonardsShape = LEONARDS_FIRST_SHAPE
sheldonsShape = SHELDONS_FIRST_SHAPE
roundsToPlay = NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS

main() # This must be the LAST statement of the program (DO NOT INDENT)
```

so the output is always leonard wins every game, and regardless of changes so far this output doesn't change and sheldon never wins any games. i was wondering where i went wrong in the code for this to be happening.
I've tried altering the code to be both "ROCK", "SCISSORS", and so forth as well as the numerical representation but the code still reads the outcome as leonard always wins

Comment: Please shorten your post to relevant code only. Thank you!

Comment: `determineWinner` is mind blowing. except that you only forgot a million other meaningful combinations

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with these parts of your code:

```
def determineLeonardsNextShape(roundOutcome):
  ...
  return determineLeonardsNextShape == 3
  ...

def determineSheldonsNextShape(roundOutcome):
  ...
  return determineSheldonsNextShape == 3
  ...

def determineWinner():
  ...
  return determineWinner == LEONARD_WINS
  ...
```

You are returning the comparison between a function and an `int`?
I think what you meant to do was to simply return a specific value.

You can trace the problem in `playGame` and `updateScores`:

- `determineWinner` is a function while `LEONARD_WINS`/`SHELDON_WINS`/`TIE` are all `ints` (you can check by using [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#type) or by printing the objects directly), so all the comparisons you made in `determineWinner` will **always** return `False`
- `updateScores` will then **always** be called with `False`
- `roundOutcome` will then **always** be `False`
- `roundOutcome == LEONARD_WINS` will **always** be `True` (`False == 0`)

Therefore, Leonard always wins.
The same logic applies to `determineLeonardsNextShape` and `determineSheldonsNextShape` which also always returns `False` and will fall through the `== 0` comparison.

Replace **ALL** those `return determine<something> == <value>` with just `return <value>`:

```
def determineLeonardsNextShape(roundOutcome):
  ...
  return 3
  ...

def determineSheldonsNextShape(roundOutcome):
  ...
  return 3
  ...

def determineWinner():
  ...
  return LEONARD_WINS
  ...
```

I think you'll get the desired behavior after that:

```
Jason Bolling
project 4: Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock
Ima Python Programmer
Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock

roundOutcome=1
roundOutcome=1
roundOutcome=0
roundOutcome=2
Sheldon's initial move: Spock
Leonard's initial move: Scissors

Sheldon wins! 
Sheldon won 2 game(s), Leonard won 1 game(s), and they tied 1 game(s)
```